# Swift: Move button above keyboard and stay

Tags: swift

I am attempting to move my button up when my textField becomeFirstResponder and keep it there. My code works until I started typing on the textField, and the button then reverts to its original location, ie behind the keyboard.

My code as such:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(exchangeButton)

    exchangeButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    exchangeButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true
    exchangeButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    exchangeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

    subscribeToShowKeyboardNotifications()
    amountTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

}

@objc func keyboardDidShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        let keyboardSize = userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
        self.exchangeButton.frame.origin.y = self.exchangeButton.frame.origin.y - keyboardHeight
    }

func subscribeToShowKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardDidShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
}
```

Note that I would like the textField to becomeFirstResponder immediately when this VC is launched and thus assigning becomeFirstResponder in viewDidLoad.

Also, I have attempted using UIKeyboardWillShow and at viewWillAppear as well. Under those scenarios, my button does not relocate.

My reference: [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468267/move-uibutton-above-keyboard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are mixing using auto-layout ant trying to manually position the button.  Initially you set the position and size of the button by setting up some constraints in your viewDidLoad.  Then when the keyboard appears you manually change the origin of the button which initially appears to work (it moves to where you want it).  However what then happens is that when the layout of the owning view is updated the constraints are applied again thus moving the button back to where it should be.  Typing text is probably enough to force the layout to happen.

To overcome this you need to adjust the constraint instead of manually setting the frame.  Here is an example test class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var testTextField: UITextField!

    var testButton: UIButton!
    var buttonConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        testButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
        testButton.backgroundColor = .green
        self.view.addSubview(testButton)
        testButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        testButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        testButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
        testButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -40).isActive = true

        buttonConstraint = testButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10)
        buttonConstraint.isActive = true

        testButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        subscribeToShowKeyboardNotifications()
        testTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        let keyboardSize = userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
        buttonConstraint.constant = -10 - keyboardHeight
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        buttonConstraint.constant = -10
    }

    func subscribeToShowKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func buttonAction() {
        testTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Now you will probably want to do something better than hardcoding the original position to -10 but that is up to you.

Note I have used .UIKeyboardWillShow and .UIKeyboardWillHide to make it all look good.  Also to have it animate you can do this:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardSize = userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    let keyboardHeight = keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
    buttonConstraint.constant = -10 - keyboardHeight

    let animationDuration = userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    buttonConstraint.constant = -10

    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let animationDuration = userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

which animates the button moving along with the keyboard.